# Copied variable changes the original?

Tags: python, variables

I have a simple problem in Python that is very very strange.

```
def estExt(matriz,erro):
    # (1) Determinar o vector X das soluções
    print ("Matrix after:");
    print(matriz);

    aux=matriz;
    x=solucoes(aux); # IF aux is a copy of matrix, why the matrix is changed??

    print ("Matrix before: ");
    print(matriz)

...
```

As you see below, the matrix `matriz` is changed in spite of the fact that `aux` is the one being changed by the function `solucoes()`.

Matrix before:
`[[7, 8, 9, 24], [8, 9, 10, 27], [9, 10, 8, 27]]`

Matrix after:
`[[7, 8, 9, 24], [0.0, -0.14285714285714235, -0.2857142857142847, -0.42857142857142705],
  [0.0, 0.0, -3.0, -3.0000000000000018]]`

Answer (score 128, accepted):

The line

```
aux=matriz;
```

Does not make a copy of `matriz`, it merely creates a new reference to `matriz` named `aux`.  You probably want

```
aux=matriz[:]
```

Which will make a copy, assuming `matriz` is a simple data structure.  If it is more complex, you should probably use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)

```
aux = copy.deepcopy(matriz)
```

As an aside, you don't need semi-colons after each statement, python doesn't use them as EOL markers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer =) But i have a another question considering this fact: if b=1 and a=b, if we change a=3, the b is not changed in python. Why? Thanks =)

Comment: Because you're changing `a` to point to a different object (the integer `3`), but not changing `b`, so it still points to `1`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Also FYI: if you want to deep copy a `dict` structure, you probably want the `dictionary.copy()`

Answer (score 29):

Use [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module

```
aux = copy.deepcopy(matriz) # there is copy.copy too for shallow copying
```

Minor one: semicolons are not needed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow @AndréFreitas. Usually here, it is considered a good community practice to accept one of the answers (one which you think is best, not necessarily mine).

Answer (score 7):

`aux` is *not* a copy of `matrix`, it's just a different name that refers to the same object.

Use the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) to create actual copies of your objects.