# Creating an array of object copies?

Tags: python, arrays, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to make an array of some objects (another array or dict), like:

```
a = {"authorName" : 0}
b = [a] * numOfAuthors     # numOfAuthors = 300, predefined
```

My objective is that each element in b should be a copy of a, such that they can be modified independently without affecting each other, but clearly the code shown will result in: modifications to any element in b will be reflected to all others due to the assignment. Hence I tried changing it to:

```
b = [copy.deepcopy(a)] * numOfAuthors
```

from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122627/the-copy-variable-changes-the-original-var-in-python). But it's still behaving in the old way. If I do:

```
b[0]["Ben"] = 12
```

then b will be a list of {"Ben": 12}. How should I resolve this?

Comment: Multiplication doesn't make copies of the contents of the list, so `[<whatever>] * <num>` produces a list with `<num>` references to one object `<whatever>`.

Comment: `[copy.deepcopy(a)] * numOfAuthors` -> `[copy.deepcopy(a) for _ in xrange(numOfAuthors)]`