# Python - Two Classes's Variables Are Linked

Tags: python-3.x, class, local-variables

I noticed this problem in something I was making, and managed to reproduce it in a simpler form.

The problem is that I have two players - both of a Person class - and they each have their own grid. I start off with a global grid variable and assign each Person's grid to that global variable. However, when I change one Person's grid, the other Person's grid changes, too!

Here's the code and output:

[image: Code image]

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this happens?

EDIT:

I tried the list() suggestion. This worked in one program, but in my main program it didn't do anything.

```
Players[1].Grid = list(Grid)

Players[0].Grid = list(Grid)
```

This outputs the same thing when I changed on of the lists.

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Scovetta's answer did work for the example I provided, the code in which I found the problem actually used a 2-Dimensional list, rather than the 1-Dimensional one in the sample.

I have found out from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122627/copied-variable-changes-the-original) that more complex objects need

```
copy.deepcopy
```

to copy everything, without being just a reference to the old variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're sharing the grid between both objects, so when you change it, they both see it. If you want each to have a copy of it, use list() to make a copy of it.

```
People[a].grid = list(Grid)
```

Comment: Agree with @Woafer, `deepcopy` is needed for complex objects.