# How to avoid mutating original global variable when creating copy

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a homework assignment and I'm running into a weird issue with python I don't quite understand. I am creating an abacus based on some input number and to do this I created a base abacus or an "empty" abacus representing 0 as a global variable. In my function I set the new_abacus value equal to the empty_abacus global variable; but for some reason when I change the new_abacus variable the empty_abacus variable also changes.

Inside my function:

```py
def function(input_num):  
  global empty_abacus
  new_abacus = empty_abacus 

  #I then change the new_abacus variable

  return new_abacus
```

When I try printing out empty_abacus after using this function it has been changed. I assume this is some weird thing with global variable in pythons. How can I prevent empty_abacus from being changed when I change new_abacus. Or in other words, how can I assign new_abacus the value of empty_abacus; rather than a reference.

Note: empty_abacus is a 2-dimensional list

EDIT: I apologize if the title is misleading, I'm not sure how to put it in words.

Comment: What is the type of `empty_abacus`? Assigning it to another name will not create a copy, and if it's mutable, changes will be reflected on the original copy.

Comment: Its a 2 dimensional list

Comment: Now, people, _this_ is how you should ask a homework assignment question.

Comment: I'm not sure you need `global empty_abacus`, since you aren't trying to mutate `empty_abacus`, just get a copy. I'd do `new_abacus = copy.deepcopy(empty_abacus)`, where `deepcopy` will return exactly that, a deeply copied (but new) object

Comment: Use the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#module-copy) module to make a copy.

Comment: One key piece of knowledge that you need here is: in Python, assignment *never* copies data. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of your issue here is `new_abacus = empty_abacus`, which doesn't perform how you think it would. `empty_abacus` is passed by reference, which means that both `new_abacus` and `empty_abacus` will point to the same position in memory. Changes to one of the two will affect the same space in memory.

Instead, [make a copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) of `empty_abacus` within `new_abacus`:

```
import copy

# ... other code here ...

new_abacus = copy.deepcopy(empty_abacus)
```

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer. I'm very used to c++ where everything pretty much everything copies by value unless you specify otherwise. Python is a big change from that.

Comment: If you dont want your `empty_abacus` to change, then you need to remove the statement `global empty_abacus` from your function.

Answer (score 0):

new_abacus = empty_abacus

This line does not make copy of the variable instead refer it as same variable.

You need to create another copy of variable depending upon the data type:
Some like this makes it more clearer:
[Copied variable changes the original?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122627/copied-variable-changes-the-original)

As mentioned in the comments:
new_abacus = copy.deepcopy(empty_abacus)

This will create a another copy so you are not refering to same object in the memory

Comment: Solution for anyone looking in the future:

Comment: new_abacus = copy.deepcopy(empty_abacus)